# Change just the cell on a LiPo battery

Tags: lipo, cell

This question is more to understand why it hasn't work for me, this is the case:
I have an old Kindle 2nd generation e-reader, the batteries are almost depleted, working just a few minutes. So I have this other batteries, from a phone, same voltage a little more mah, 1530mAh vs 1500. The size was almost the same, so it seems to me that it was worth the try. Removed the kindle's battery little board and connected the battery cell to it, but it didn't work, so I wanted to know why.

Thanks.

Comment: Wrong polarity, wrong connections, connections didn't align.....

Comment: Maybe there is a fault with the electronics draing the battery too fast

Comment: Polarity was fine, using multimeter, marked everything, the output of the cell board has voltage, so in theory it should work?

Comment: Perhaps the thermistor measurement pin(s) are missing / open circuit?